# Validates resource references inside Android XML files on my fragment example

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am creating a fragment example, but I have a problem in `AndroidManifest.xml`

> < activity android:name=".MainActivity"> is not a concrete class. Validates resource references inside Android XML files

I have tried invalidate caches/restart, but it is cannot solved.

```
MainActivity.java
```

[image: Main activity.java]

```
AndroidManifest.xml
```

[image: AndroidManifest]

```
fragment.java
```

[image: fragment]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `abstract` keyword from your activity declaration:

> ```
> public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity implements ...
> ```

Your manifest is saying that `MainActivity` is the home screen of your app, so the system needs to be able to instantiate it. The `abstract` keyword says that it's impossible to instantiate the class. So you either have to remove the `abstract` keyword, or you have to create a concrete subclass of `MainActivity` and use *that* in the manifest.

Comment: how can i create subclass ?